# Set Data Source Option in ArcGIS Pro - Similar to set data source for mxd

Tags: arcgis-pro, data-source

Where can I find following option to change data source of all layers in map in ArcGIS Pro?

*This is how I access data source in ArcMap*

[image]

Comment: What are you right-clicking on to see that context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for ArcGIS Pro's *Update Data Sources* tool.

There are several ways to open it:

- Right-click a map in the Table of Contents and select *Update Data Sources*
- Right-click a map in the Catalog Pane and select *Update Data Sources*
- In Catalog View (opened by clicking *Catalog View* in the View
  ribbon) click *Data Sources*

Note - I have found selecting *Validate and Apply*, rather than *Apply*, works best when updating database connections (your *New Path* must be a valid/existing connection).

Answer (score 5):

Right click the layer and select `Properties`. Then choose the `Source` tab on the left and you will see a `Set Data Source` button in the upper right.

[image: Example]

Comment: This for each layer
i am looking to do it for all layers in a map

Comment: You can use arcpy to update easily update many data sources https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/updatingandfixingdatasources.htm